# How to force python lxml not to quote attributes with <?php ... ?> inclusions?

Tags: php, python, lxml

I need to generate html fragments of a php-module with python lxml.
My code is rather huge, so it is maybe not necessary to post the whole stuff, but in general it does something like this:

```
element = html.Element("input", name="field", type="text", value="<?php $field ?>")
```

The problem is that et.tostring quotes the value, so that the result looks like this:

```
<input class="ml" type="text" name="field" value="&lt;?php $field ?&gt;">
```

Expected output should be:

```
<input class="ml" type="text" name="field" value="<?php $field ?>">
```

Is it possible to do so?